# Omniauth Custom rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, omniauth

How could I map this action

```
match '/auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'
```

which gets called via

```
<b><%= link_to "Sign in with Facebook", "/auth/facebook", id: "sign_in" %></b>
```

to a path like login_path or to work with a subURI?

I have tried  to: "sessions#create", as: "login" but this errors out with no routes matches for sessions#create. Thanks in advance!

Comment: my app is deployed to www.domain.com/rails_app which is a subURI of the domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you got confused a little.

This route you've talking about is the callback which the user is returned to *after* OmniAuth communicated with the 3rd-party service (eg. Facebook). So there's no point in naming this route using the `:as` option (although you could).

What you want to edit (if I understood you) is the URL the user hits to Login so it doesn't look like http://example.com/auth/facebook but it looks like http://example.com/login.

It's just a static url (/auth/facebook) so you could just redirect it like this:

`match "/login" => redirect("/auth/github")`

If the URL that is visible to the user doesn't concern you but you just want to simplify it inside your views like:

`<b><%= link_to "Sign in with Facebook", sign_in, id: "sign_in" %></b>`

you could define this method in a helper (ApplicationHelper.rb for example):

```
def login_link
  "/auth/facebook"
end
```

although I don't see any particular reason for doing this.

Comment: Hi Agis, sorry for late replies, the match"/login" with a redirect seems perfect. my issue was that my app was visiting domain.com/auth/facebook and not domain.com/app/auth/facebook. i dont mind what the user sees from that perspective but was trying to hard code it so the paths remain consistent across environments. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`match '/auth/:provider/callback' => 'sessions#create'`

The above routing code will help you, if you wan the `/auth/twitter(:provider)/callback` to end in your `SessionsController` => `create` action